# Gradle not working inside container but does outside

Tags: docker, gradle

For some reason gradle is not working for me from w/in a docker container.  Of course, outside the container it works fine.  What's strange is that it doesn't say what file or directory is missing.

```
# ./gradlew clean -s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'foo-bar'.
  > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.9.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-gradle-plugin/0.8.9/protobuf-gradle-plugin-0.8.9.pom'.
        > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:  (No such file or directory)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.DefaultSslContextFactory$SslContextCacheLoader.initTrustManagerFactory(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:146)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.DefaultSslContextFactory$SslContextCacheLoader.load(DefaultSslContextFactory.java:119)
        ... 248 more
```

Comment: This seems like an SSL error. What (base-)image are you using?

Comment: It's a prepared one that all our teams are suppose to use, maybe I need to modify or add to it?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the (base-)image. I know that java can be picky wrt. SSL-certificates. Then again, I am not sure whether this is  a problem with JDK version or gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears the problem was that **javax.net.ssl.trustStore** was being set to blank and overwriting the default, which also explains why FileNotFoundException appeared to not specify a value.